# How do I access input devices on WSL2?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

When i type `cat /dev/input`, there is no directory.

When i type `cat /proc/bus/input/devices`, there is nothing there too.

Cause I used to type these commands on my VMWare Ubuntu, and they work just fine.

I even wrote a simple driver modules as input device just for test, still nothing, but insmoding the module successfully.

So where is my mouse or keyboard devices? Where does the system store them?

BTW I am using WSL2, ubuntu 20.04, and the WSL2 kernel has been compiled by default except some VERSION info, if that matters.

Comment: cat is the command to view the content of the files, ls is the command to see list of file. Do you meant ls there?

Comment: Of course not. The problem being on WSL2, there are some missing files and directories about input devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behaviour as Windows does not have yet the feature to automatically connect USB devices to other machines, e.g. WSL 2.

However, there is an open-source project called **[usbipd-win](https://github.com/dorssel/usbipd-win)** which allows sharing locally connected USB devices to other machines, including Hyper-V and WSL 2.

Here is an [instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/connect-usb) to connect a USB device to a Linux distribution running on WSL 2.

Once you connect your device to a Linux on WSL 2, you can check the ID, BUS and Device number with `lsubs` command.

Comment: Thx but there is still one thing confuses me: what happens if I insmod a module as input subsystem on WSL2? How can I check it? I assume that it is not within USB device, right?
In another word, what if my input device is not a USB device?

Comment: It seems that the base WSL2 kernel does not allow modules to be loaded. You have to compile and use your own kernel build. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/645131/393118. Please consider up/downvoting or accepting the answer if it was or was not helpful.

Comment: I had already compiled my WSL2 kernel like I mentioned above and I can insmod modules like chrdev or misc dev correctly. And I can also find those device nodes on my WSL2.

But when it comes to input device module, it doesn't seem to work that way. I guess I will probably need a full Linux installation.